# Meaning of "しっかり体験して"?

Tags: words

My correspondent wrote me this:

> (...) 日本の気候をしっかり体験していってくださいね

The dictionary isn't helping much here... "Please steadily/firmly/properly/wisely experience Japan's climate"? There are so many meanings of しっかり it is difficult to tell what is meant here. Context was difficult weather like rainstorms and typhoons.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In that context, 「しっかり」 would mean something like "to the fullest".

> "Please experience the Japanese climate to the fullest (before you return home)!"

Answer (score 1):

The fact that the writer said this in connection with storms and typhoons makes this clear. It means, literally,'please experience the Japanese weather with fortitude'. What the writer is saying is 'You'll find the weather pretty rough, but I hope you'll bear it with fortitude and regard it as an [interesting/instructive] experience.' Since the tone of the Japanese is informal I'd translate this, if asked, as 'The Japanese weather can be quite harsh, so just grin and bear it - it'll be an experience!'